# Getting error in Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda==4.8.4 while downloading package from requirement.txt?

Tags: python

I am trying to install all the required packages of the **project from requirement.txt** but I get lot of similar errors like I am using python 3.9.1

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement conda==4.8.4 (from versions: 3.0.6, 3.5.0, 3.7.0, 3.17.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.2, 4.1.6, 4.2.6, 4.2.7, 4.3.13, 4.3.16)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for conda==4.8.4
```

also there are package name like

```
backports.functools-lru-cache @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.functools_lru_cache_1605305165209/work
```

**how to install these kind of packages** ?

Comment: what is your python version ?

Comment: python 3.9.1 version

Comment: If you are getting several errors related to the package version, please check the python version used for creating the project.

Comment: What package manager are you using `pip` or `conda` ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar are you sure this is related to python version ? and what about this file location `backports.functools-lru-cache @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.functools_lru_cache_1605305165209/work`

Comment: @Kishore I am using pip version 20.3.1

Comment: I guess you should use `conda` because there is no conda version (4.8.4) in [`PyPI` here](https://pypi.org/project/conda/#history) but there is one for [`conda` here](https://conda.io/projects/continuumio-conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#id14)

Comment: Yes. If I were you, I would look for the difference in python version.

Comment: Regarding the second error, I have never come across that type of entry in the `requirements.txt` file. The path looks like a reference to some local path. I am not sure what that means.

Comment: @PrashantKumar But there is no conda version `conda==4.8.4` available in `PyPI`. That's why `pip` is raising the above error. But I am also not sure of what `backports.functools-lru-cache @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.functools_lru_cache_1605305165209/work` this line is.

Comment: On the conda github page it specifies this `drop Python 2.7 and add Python 3.9 ` for release `conda 4.10.0`. Anyways, @swatigoel please try installing with conda instead of pip. Hope it works